# How to check if element in list matches with another element in a list of strings?

Tags: python

## Input lists

```
list1 = ['Google', 'Stanford University', 'Karlsruhe Institute of Technology (KIT) / University of Karlsruhe (TH)', 'AU-KBC Research Centre']
exclusion_list = ['university','institute','school','University','Institute','School']
```

## Output list

```
output=['Google','AU-KBC Research Centre']
```

The output should have only those elements which do not contain the words(elements) from the `exclusion_list`
I have searched all of SO. But, none of them give an answer to specifically this problem. I have tried using `filter()` and also a dumb function. But, I am looking for a non-brute-force solution. Also, I am curious about an extra solution which uses regex to solve the problem.

## Basically

I am looking for an optimal way to remove any sort of university, school or institute from the `list1`

> EDIT: I want to preserve the order of the list as well. I apologize for not making this point clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
list1 = ['Google', 'Stanford University', 'Karlsruhe Institute of Technology (KIT) / University of Karlsruhe (TH)', 'AU-KBC Research Centre']
exclusion_list = ['university','institute','school','University','Institute','School']
exclusion_list = [i.lower() for i in exclusion_list]
for i in list1:
    if not any(map(lambda x:x in i.lower(), exclusion_list)):
        print(i)
```

Comment: This answer is more readable and preserves the order! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For an efficient solution you might want to use `sets` here. Define `exclusion_list` as a `set`, and use a list comprehension to check membership on each of the words in `list1`:

```
list1 = ['Google', 'Stanford University',
         'Karlsruhe Institute of Technology (KIT) / University of Karlsruhe (TH)', 
         'AU-KBC Research Centre']

# define a set from the exclusion_list
exclusion_list = set(['university','institute','school','University','Institute','School'])

[i for i in list1 if not set(i.split()).intersection(exclusion_list)]
# ['Google', 'AU-KBC Research Centre']
```

Comment: If you add `i.lower().split()` in the condition, you only need lower case words in the exclusion list

Answer (score 1):

We can do something like follows:

```py
out = []
excl = set(exclusion_list)
for item in list1:
    for word in item.split():
        if word in excl:
            break
    else:
        out.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
k = pd.Series(['Google', 'Stanford University', 'Karlsruhe Institute of Technology (KIT) / University of Karlsruhe (TH)', 'AU-KBC Research Centre'])
k[~k.str.contains('|'.join(exclusion_list))].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```py
[s for s in list1 if not any(e in s.lower() for e in exclusion_list)]
```

Similarly possible with filter as you mentioned:

```py
list(filter(lambda s: not any(e in s.lower() for e in exclusion_list), list1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[name  for name in list1 if not any(x.lower() in name.lower() for x in set(exclusion_list)) ]
```